# 301 redirection with Squid based on URL (is Squirm the fastest way?)

Tags: squid, reverse-proxy, 301-redirect

I am using Squid 2.6 as a reverse proxy. I am receiving all the traffic from several domain names (.com .org etc.) but the website is always the same. I would like to have only one domain (specially for SEO reasons) so I would like Squid to redirect those domains with a `301 Moved Permanently` HTTP header to the main one. Note that I also want to redirect internal pages. What is the best way (taking into consideration performance and speed) to do so? Squirm?